# Find keyframes in AVI, H.264 file

Tags: c++, video, h.264, avi, mpeg-4

My goal is to search keyframes in AVI file. I parse it and get all the data chunks for the video stream, but how can i find in there info about frames themselves - whether a particular frame is a keyframe or not?

Comment: meta: how is this question "unspecific"? it clearly states what it wishes to do and what it did already. could we reopen it or make a more specific comment on what's wrong, should there be anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword is `AVIIF_KEYFRAME`. See http://www.opennet.ru/docs/formats/avi.txt

> AVIIF_KEYFRAME
>
> Indicates this chunk is a key frame. Key frames do not require
>   additional preceding chunks to be properly decoded.